# How to post a JSON request in Jersey-Test

Tags: java, json, jersey

I'm writing unit test for my REST application, and i'm stuck. When i used header parameters, tests were obvious. But now, my requests are in JSON, and i dont know how to test it. Maybe there is a way to do it with Jersey or maybe with Jackson.
My line where i get the response from my resource looks like this:

```
final Response response = RULE.getJerseyTest().target("/actors/1").request().post(/* json request */);
```

Where the RULE is ResourceTestRule.

What should i do with it to make it POST a resource?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you call [`request()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/WebTarget.html#request--) on the `WebTarget` (`target("/actors/1")`), you get back an [`Invocation.Builder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Invocation.Builder.html), which extends [`SyncInvoker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/SyncInvoker.html). If you look at all the `post()` methods on the `SyncInvoker`, you will see that they all take [`Entity`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Entity.html)

- `Response post(Entity<?> entity)`
- `<T> T post(Entity<?> entity, Class<T> responseType)`
- `<T> T post(Entity<?> entity, GenericType<T> responseType)`

If you look at the `Entity` class, you will just see a bunch of static methods like `form`, `html`, `json`, `xml`, `text`. Just pass in your entity (JSON POJO) to the `json` method to create an `Entity` of type `application/json`.

```
...request().post(Entity.json(yourPojo));
```

You should go through all the javadoc links I provided to get familiar with the APIs, at least so you know what's going on behind all those chained method calls.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what i searched for, everything works just as i expected!